# Azure SQL best way to update a row, add a number to existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sqlperformance

So, it would be a very simple update: `UPDATE TableA SET columnB = columnB + @numbervalue WHERE id=@id`

Now this seems to be using a lot of the db right now (possibly we can do it in batches later, but for now, just wondering a few things)

Should I add `OPTION (MAXDOP 1)` to the end? Would it be faster if it were a double vs an int? If it's always adding 1 is there a better way increment 1? thing I should do if this query is the highest load on the db?

Comment: Do you mean that it takes a long time to execute the update? If "id" is the primary key, it should not take a long time unless you have triggers or something similar (in that case maybe you should paste them here).

Comment: For better help we need to see a query plan (share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan) and preferably table and index definitions also

Comment: Well, for example, should I use double, or MAXDOP ? probably better to put in a stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Below are few tips to increase the performance of the query:

- Create an **index** on the filtered column to avoid table scan.
- Remove index on update columns before the update. This increases performance and you can add index again after the update.
- Remove triggers on the table, if possible, when you are doing large updates.
- Removing indexes on the table which not being used can increase your update performance.

As Query Optimizer selects the best execution plan for a query, it is recommended to use hints as a last resort.

The **Max Degree of parallelism** is to set the number of processors to run a single statement for each parallel plan execution.

In the Azure SQL database, the **MAXDOP** setting for each database is set to **8**. This default prevents unnecessary resource utilization while executing queries faster using parallel threads.

Check this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/configure-max-degree-of-parallelism#overview) which describes the database behavior with different MAXDOP values.

You can override the MAXDOP value to add at query level using the **MAXDOP query hint** as below.

`OPTION (MAXDOP 4)`

Int uses fewer bytes (4 bytes) and has the least amount of IO. It has more performance benefits if you are storing integer values in a column.